# How did Allah swt reveal a perfect Qur'an using an imperfect language?

Tags: quran

I have heard a non-muslim asking this question I have a heard a Muslim responding by saying that language was taught by Allah swt to Adam (as) (Suggested in Qur'an 2:31, and also explained here - https://islamqa.info/en/answers/4622/what-are-the-things-that-allaah-taught-to-adam) and that Arabic is linked to that original language, therefore language in itself is not imperfect.

However, doesn't this mean that from the original language of Adam (as), changes were made to form the Arabic language. So it has imperfections as mankind was involved in it, making it an imperfect language? How do we reconcile this with the fact that the Qur'an is perfect?

Comment: I don't know where you get this claim from. Actually the linked fatwa says something different it speaks of names of everything and every creation not of language at all.

Answer (score 0):

> The content of the Qur'an can be summarised as explaining humanity's
> great unknowns (ghayb) - purpose in life and how best to fulfil this
> purpose. It helps contextualise this by explaining what preceded the
> universe, the eternality of God, the gathering of the souls, the
> primordial covenant, origins of humanity via Adam and Eve, and what
> will follow it, the eternality of God, and heaven or hell. The
> contents are often divided into three categories: moral, legal and
> ethical matters; metaphysical matters including prophecies of future
> events; and religious, cultural and historical references of previous
> and contemporary nations. *Source [How would you describe the content of the Quran?](https://www.islamiqate.com/2940/how-would-you-describe-the-content-of-the-quran)*

Ibn Khaldun said in his al-Muqaddimah that the Arabic Language was perfected by the Quran. in addition, the Quran is a master work of [literature](https://www.islamiqate.com/4058/if-the-quran-is-eloquent-so-was-shakespeare-why-quran-divine). Furthermore, Allah (swt) created the languages, the humans did not. Hence, the argument that human imperfection could affect it non ill-founded. Moreover, even if it were so, Allah has promised to protect the Quran and the Deen, so there is no cause for worry.